Href link isn't directing to the other file (PHP)
Having problems with the href link not directing/displaying the other pages. In the url it says it's been directed to the other page but it doesn't display it when I tested it out. Same problem with my form action button as well.
The href link problem
<style> 
    <?php include("header.css"); ?>
</style> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sistem Kehadiran Sidang Redaksi SMK Taman Bukit Maluri</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body> 
    <!-- Banner -->
    <div class="banner">
        <h1> Sistem Kehadiran Sidang Redaksi </h1> 
        <h2> SMK Taman Bukit Maluri </h2>
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation bar-->
     <ul> 
        <li><a href="index.php"> Laman Utama </a></li>
        <li><a href="profil.php"> Profil </a></li>
        <li><a href="kehadiranRekod.php"> Kaunter Kehadiran </a></li>
        <li><a href="senaraiAhli.php"> Senarai Ahli </a></li>
        <li><a href="senaraiAktiviti.php"> Senarai Aktiviti </a></li>
        <li><a href="kehadiranLaporan.php"> Laporan Kehadiran </a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a href="logKeluar.php"> Log Keluar </a></li> 
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

The form action problem
<style>
    <?php include("logMasuk.css"); ?> 
</style>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Log Masuk Ahli </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="logMasuk.css">
</head>
<body> 
    <form action="logMasukProses.php" method="POST">
        <h2> Log Masuk </h2>

        <label> No. Kad Pengenalan </label>
        <input type="number" name="nokp" placeholder="Nombor Kad Pengenalan"> <br>

        <label> Kata Laluan </label>
        <input type="password" name="kataLaluan" placeholder="Kata Laluan"> <br>

        <button type="submit"> Log Masuk </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

logMasukProses.php
<?php
    echo "hello";
?>

Before clicking
After clicking
I checked if another element is overlapping it but it's not. I can still click on it. Tried the php echo method too, didn't work. Everything is all in the same folder

This sounds like an issue with your webserver configuration, there may be a rewrite rule that's mapping everything to the original script.

Any advice on how to fix it?

Sorry, I don't really know much about Apache configuration (I'm guessing that's what you're using). Maybe it logs something helpful. You'll need to ask on [linux.se] or [su].

The link has a relative path (logMasukProses.php). Since current page location contains a trailing slash for whatever the reason (/kehadiranSidangRedaksi/logMasukBorang.php/), the browser understands you want to append the link's path to current location. Relative links can be hard to get right, the most straightforward way to solve this is to use an absolute link, but I guess you can just not append that slash.
